# How to make automatic pop up window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

```
<input class= "buttons" type="button" name="displayjobsheet" value= "Display Job Sheet" onclick = "window.open('Xml.html','My Window','height= 480 px,width =640 ,')"/>
```

How to make a pop up window? I want it to be automatic and pop out every time i open the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "onload" event instead of "onclick" on the <body> tag (pretty sure this method is quite deprecated).

Or you can use **window.onload** event method in your script source code, like this :

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.open('Xml.html','My Window','height= 480 px,width =640 ,');
};
```

Or even better :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { ... });
```

Comment: Why wait for the `load` event?

Comment: Because the 'load' event will be triggered every time the user loads or refreshes the page. It's better to use this event instead of calling the function directly in the script because in this case, you are sure that the page is effectively loaded.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `window.open()` work *before* the page has fully loaded?

Comment: In this case, it is effectively not necessary because popup does not depend on the page content but using the load event is a good habit to take, especially when your code have to manipulate the DOM, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add event attribute to your body tag

```
onload="window.open('Xml.html','My Window','height= 480 px,width =640 ,')"
```

Comment: Why put it in an `onload`, as compared to just called it directly in a script element (without an event)?

Comment: There are lot of ways you can achieve this. For example, you can also trigger an onclick event while page load. I just try to make questioner to easily understand. And what do you mean for script element?

Comment: `<script>window.open(...)</script>` - No events, just code that runs as soon as the browser has parsed the script.

Answer (score 0):

For automatic pop on page load you can use `window.onload`.

This will call your DOM's onload method.

```
function xyz() { 

  //your logic

}

window.onload = xyz;
```

Comment: Why in an `onload` handler rather than just directly without an event?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() { 
 window.open('http://example.com','Tab Heading','height=300,width=150, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no')
}
window.onload = popup;
</script>
```

edit as your requirement.